# Unable to use mouse on text fields, have to use tab

Tags: html, forms

I've had this weird situation just popup where I'm unable to use my mouse on a form I'm creating. It's requiring me to tab through the text fields. if I click on the second field it just pushes me back to the first field, i have to tab!

this is the form totally simple, it has something to do with the labels but I have never had issues before.

BTW: no JS or CSS in this form or page

my example:

```
<form>

<label for="username"*Username label>

<input type="text" name="username" tabindex="1" id="username">

<label for="password"*Password*label*> 

<input type="password" name="password" tabindex="2" id="password">

<input type="submit" class="button" value="Login" name="submit" >

</form>
```

Comment: Please reformat your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper way to format inputs with labels. This should fix your problem.

```
<label for="username">*Username*<input type="text" name="username" tabindex="1" id="username"/></label>
<label for="password">*Password*<input type="password" name="password" tabindex="2" id="password"/></label>
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZFZgt/**